# If I copy a Folder with .git repo will it work independently of original?

Tags: git, windows-7-x64

If I copy a folder under git VC (with the appropriate .git  subfolder) will this copy then "behave" independently of the original?

What if, instead, I MOVED the folder to a new location? Would it behave as it did previously? (I.e., the move doesn't affect anything)

Comment: Yes. Git is a distributed file system. Git has no built-in mechanism for automatically syncing repositories. Hell, git doesn't even have a concept of "forks" or "pull requests".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I replace a Git repo with its backup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40027493/can-i-replace-a-git-repo-with-its-backup)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions about the same issue. I've flagged this question as a duplicate of another question that you recently posted. If you have more information to add, then please [edit](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your original question to add that information, rather than asking a new question.

Comment: @JackManey "Git has no concept of pull requests" is half-right, see [docs for `git request-pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull). (All that does is generate a message that can be emailed to the repo maintainer, so it's definitely not what most people think of when they hear the term "pull request".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The folder with the .git directory is what makes it a git repository.  If you copy the folder, you're making a copy of the local repository and it is completely independent of the original repository.

If you move a repository and do a `git status`, you'll notice that nothing is seen as having changed.  Git does track if you move files or folders within the repository, but not the repository itself.